# Regex to get string after a character ending with another optional character and not matching it

Tags: php, regex

I'm struggling with a regex, here's an example of the input string

test#string=val

i need to get "string" no matter what's inside it (including special charso but bviously not including the '=') it's always preceded by the '#' character, but i don't need it included. The word ahead of it ('test' in this case), is also optional.

The '=' is optional, but if it's there i need it to be ignored. I've been using something like this

```
#([\w\W]*)
```

But i can't manage to handle the optional '='

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
#([^=]*)
```

This matches anything after `#` that is not a `=`. It doesn’t matter whether there is actually a `=` following or not.

Comment: Ah excellent i was so close i actually tried #([\w\W^=]*) once and of course it didn't work; this looks great so far, i'll test it and accept it if everything goes well

Comment: Found a little problem, i only need the first ocurrence of it, for example if i type -> string#test1#test2=somethinghere#alsohere the result should be 'test1#test2' is that possible?

Comment: @Kusanagi2k: What language do you use?

Comment: It's in PHP, i know i know, i'm being a little lazy and picky, i know i can give it to an array using something like 'preg_match('/#([^=]*)/', $str, $result)' and then using $result[1]; as the variable i want, but you know, just in case and for learning regexes purposes i wanted it clean =P

Comment: @Kusanagi2k: Doing so is clean. Using something like `/(?<=#)[^=]*/` is possible too but it makes it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help, effort and comments

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which language. In php you can do:

```
<?php
preg_match('~#(([^=#]*))~', $str, $m );
var_dump($m[1]); // $m[1] is your string here
?>
```

Comment: uhmm yeah it's in PHP but since in this solution you're using \w then something like 'test[123]' will only result in 'test' since you're using the word delimiter

Comment: But I thought you said `=` is optional after the string. `[^=]*` will grab `text1#text2` in text `#text1#text2` but I believe you may only want `text1` there.

Comment: The '=' is optional yeah but the given answer is '#([^=]*)' not '[^=]*'. I assume that what solution ('#([^=]*)') means is to grab anything after a '#' which doesn't contain '=' which works for me.
Also if there's #text1#text2 the result (using Gumbo's answer) is 'text1#text2' which also works

Comment: If you want to grab `#text1#text2` then `([^=]*)` will work fine as per Gumbo's answer. But if you just want to grab `text1` then `[^=#]*` will work better (see my edit above).

Comment: It's good for reference in case any other user needs it, still thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think it's better if you use simpler functions like `explode(,'#')` and/or `strpos`.

They are suggested for simple string manipulation like this